# Concatenate and flat two nested python list

Tags: python, list, nested

I have two vectors in the form

```
a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

b = [[5,6,7],[5,6,7],[5,6,7]]
```

I want the output to be

```
c = [[1,2,3,5,6,7],[1,2,3,5,6,7],[1,2,3,5,6,7]]
```

I got this line

```
c = [[a[i],b[i]] for i in range(len(a))]
```

but my output is

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]], [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]], [[1, 2, 3], [5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: Better use six *different* sublists to make it more obvious where the parts in the output come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*zip*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and *concatenate* each pairing:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]]

b = [[5,6,7],[5,6,7],[5,6,7]]

print([i + j for i,j in zip(a, b)])
```

Which would give you:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Or using your own logic:

```
[a[i] + b[i] for i in range(len(a))]
```

*concatenating*  with + is the key. If you were going to index I would use [*enumerate*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
[ele + b[i] for i, ele in enumerate(a)]
```

Comment: that's a nice way, I have several features vectors, and I need it to create an array as input for a scikit learn classifier

Answer (score 2):

Just another way:

```
>>> map(list.__add__, a, b)
[[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Or using the `operator` module:

```
>>> map(operator.add, a, b)
[[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]]
```

Comment: I'm going with padraic's solution since It could be extended to more lists in the form    [ele + b[i] + c[i] for i, ele in enumerate(a)]

Answer (score -1):

Here's a solution using the itertools module:

```
from itertools import chain, starmap
c = map(list, list(starmap(chain, zip(a, b))))
```

Edited thanks to Padraic's comment. It's too nested at this point for me to recommend using this.

Comment: This would give you a list of chain objects. It would be `list(starmap(operator.add, zip(a, b)))` if anything or `list(starmap(list.__add__, zip(a, b)))`.

Comment: My bad, edited.

Comment: I think the operator approach is nicer as you would also need an additional list call on map so it would actually become `list(map(list, list(starmap(chain, zip(a, b)))))`

Comment: Map can operate on generators so you don't need the list call around starmap.

Comment: Try it with Python 3

Comment: Try running `list(map(str, chain((1,2), (3,4))))`. There are no chain objects in the result. Map takes any iterable and results in an iterator.

Comment: You are wrapping the map in a list call which is exactly what I said you would have to do so I don't quite get your point. map(list... is going to give you a map object not a list in python3

Comment: I was saying that the list call around starmap was unecessary.